# A JSON object must begin with "{"

Tags: json, processing

I'm having trouble having Processing (v.3.0.1) to read a JSON file, I get back the error on the title.

This is part of the JSON file (minus several hundred objects similar to the ones I show):

```
{
"matches":[
      {
         "p1":{
            "reds":0,
            "team":"Liverpool",
            "goals":1
         },
         "p2":{
            "reds":0,
            "team":"Bayern Munich",
            "goals":2
         },
         "match":1
      },
      {
         "p1":{
            "reds":0,
            "team":"Psg",
            "goals":3
         },
         "p2":{
            "reds":1,
            "team":"Manchester City",
            "goals":0
         },
         "match":2
      }
   ]
}
```

And this is the Processing sketch where I try to read the JSON file:

```
String filename = "data.json"; 
JSONObject json;

Match[] matches;
Player[] allPlayers; 


void setup(){
  loadData();  
  size(600,300);
}

void draw(){
  background(40);
}

void loadData(){
  json = loadJSONObject(filename); // This is where the error happens
  JSONArray matchesData = json.getJSONArray("matches");
  matches= new Match[matchesData.size()]; 

  for(int i=0; i<matchesData.size(); i++){

    JSONObject match = matchesData.getJSONObject(i);  

    JSONObject p1 = matchesData.getJSONObject(0); 
    String p1Team = p1.getString("team");
    int p1Goals = p1.getInt("goals");
    int p1Reds = p1.getInt("reds");

    JSONObject p2 = matchesData.getJSONObject(1);

    String p2Team = p2.getString("team");
    int p2Goals = p2.getInt("goals");
    int p2Reds = p2.getInt("reds");

    int matchNum = match.getInt("match");

    allPlayers[0] = new Player("p1", p1Team, p1Goals, p1Reds);
    allPlayers[1] = new Player("p2", p2Team, p2Goals, p2Reds);

    matches[i] = new Match(matchNum, allPlayers[0], allPlayers[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to load just the json you've showed us? Can you show us the full content of the json file?

Comment: The same error happens. The JSON files doesn't seem to be the problem, but I can't find anything wrong with the code either.

Comment: I just ran your code with the json you specified, and it worked fine for me. Are you sure you're loading the file you think you're loading?

Comment: Could you post the first characters of the JSON file? And are you sure the file is in the right directory?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Yes, absolutely sure. Wich processing version did you use? @mef The first characters are this: `{"matches":[` and then the objects in the array begin, there's nothing before the opening bracket, no blank spaces, no nothing. The file is indeed in the correct directory.

Comment: I'm just using Processing 3. I highly doubt it's a Processing bug. Try reading in the file and printing it out using the `loadStrings()` function. I'm willing to bet it's not loading the file you think it is.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Oh, when I read it, this is what the first characters looked like: `?{ "matches":[`. What does that question mark mean? Obviously is not written in the file.

Comment: @maurilop You might have an invisible control character in there? Try getting the first character and printing out its unicode value.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'm sorry, how do I print its unicode value?

Comment: @maurilop The real goal is to figure out what that character is. I'd google "java convert char to unicode" or "java convert char to ascii". You might also try simply copying the json from your question into a file and trying that.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Well, it seems that the `?` equals to the hex value of `feff` wich equals to the text value of `þÿ`. I'm completely lost.

Comment: Did the ascii conversion and `?` equals to `�O`. But I found that saving the JSON file with the ANSI codification does not result in an error and the `?` disapears, maybe that was the problem from the begining? (I was using UTF-8 codification before)

Comment: @maurilop Does that mean you've solved your problem?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Yes it does, thank you very much for your help!